# Export entire module as constructor

Tags: typescript

Say I have a nodejs module that, when I require it, it returns a constructor function to me. Something like the following:

```
var Mod = require("modulename");
var mod = new Mod();
mod.method();
```

I want to write a .d.ts declaration file that can be imported and used like so:

```
import * as Mod from "mod";
let mod = new Mod();
mod.method();
```

I've tried reading all the documentation on the Typescript website but it's honestly as clear as mud, and I feel like I've tried every combination of class, interface, namespace, module and export that exists in my .d.ts file. I'm wondering if the above is even achievable. Can anybody offer any help?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of writing this

```
import * as Mod from "mod";
let mod = new Mod();
```

You should write this

```
import Mod = require("mod");
let mod = new Mod();
```

Why?

```
import * as Mod from "mod";
```

This is ES6 module import syntax. It says you're importing the `"mod"` module object into the local name `Mod`. ES6 modules only expose properties, and cannot be invoked as a function or with `new`.

I'll say this again because people often don't believe me or choose to ignore it: **ES6 modules only expose properties, and cannot be invoked as a function or with `new`.**

If you start compiling your code to an ES6 runtime (instead of downleveling to ES5 modules with CJS / AMD), your code will stop working. There's no `require` function in ES6 modules, though, so the "old-style" `import Mod = require("mod");` is still OK.

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll have a go at tinkering with my .d.ts file to try to get it working using this form of importing. Is the only way to get the ES6 module import syntax to work, then, to ask the original module author (not me) to rewrite to expose the constructor as a property rather than directly?